# How to add multiple value pairs inside a single key in a dictionary in Jquery dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to construct a dictionary for metadata in the Sharepoint list add a new item. I am trying to do it dynamically rather than hardcoding the names of the columns.

Here is the original item properties metadata that should be constructed.

```
itemProperties={"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TestingListItem"},"fldname1":"Value1","fldname1":"Value2","fldname3":"value3"};
```

This is what I have so far

```
var itemProperties={"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TestingListItem"}};
```

I run a loop here until j is let's say 5;

```
itemProperties=itemProperties+'"'+favorite[j]+'"'+':'+'"'+cells[j]+'"'+','

//favorite has the column name and cells has the values for those columns
```

I tried building a string and adding multiple values but it is not working as it supposed to.

```
itemProperties.push("Title":"AMA-424"); or 
itemProperties.append("Title":"AMA-424");**
```

I tried both but they are invalid. I am running out of ideas. I tried building the whole thing as a string but the create list item function won't take a string.

Any help or guidance highly appreciated.

Comment: I posted an answer, but your question feels like you're asking Y Question to solve X Problem. It is best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Object, you can add to it by adding more Key / Value pairs. this is done like so:

```
var obj = {};
obj['myKey'] = "myValue";
```

Consider the following example.

```js
var itemProperties = {
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.TestingListItem"
  },
  "fldname1": "Value1",
  "fldname1": "Value2",
  "fldname3": "value3"
};

var favs = [
  "Title",
  "Feature",
  "Data"
];

var cells = [
  "AMA-242",
  "One",
  "abc"
];

for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
  itemProperties[favs[i]] = cells[i];
}

console.log(itemProperties);
```

This is a Vanilla JavaScript example. Now if you want a jQuery example, I would advise using `$.extend()`.

> **Description:** Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

This is a bit like `.push()` for an Array, but for Objects. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var itemProperties = {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.Data.TestingListItem"
    },
    "fldname1": "Value1",
    "fldname1": "Value2",
    "fldname3": "value3"
  };

  var favs = {
    title: "AMA-242",
    feature: "One",
    data: 123
  };

  $.extend(itemProperties, favs);

  console.log(itemProperties);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great It worked perfectly, itemProperties[favs[i]] = cells[i]; I wonder why i never tried this. Thanks for the help :)